# Rendering Animation error

Tags: rendering, animation

When I preview my animation it looks fine and everything is there but when I actually render it it just shows one object from the animation with a white screen and not actually the whole animation.
I recorded it as well https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Cuws8NhJ4D32GGXcfJfhct6Ka8TTeRxO/view?usp=drive_link
can anyone help, how do I fix this??

Comment: First thing, your viewport is in Material preview mode, how does it look if you are in Rendered preview mode? Also check in the Outliner if you don't have an object that is disabled for preview but enabled for render?

Comment: Nothing is disabled for preview but enabled for render, changed from the Material mode to the rendering mode and still nothing

Comment: maybe share your file (remove all the objects that you don't want to share): https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Hi Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that users can at a glance understand what your post is about. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid anything not strictly essential to the post. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and makes your question findable for future users. See ["*What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: here, i just shared the file [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=z9A4jLGr" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/z9A4jLGr/)

Answer (score 1):

Shift left click twice on the *Disable in Renders* option of you collection, all your objects are disabled:

[image]

Comment: oh. thank you so so so much. I've been trying to fix this for  5+ hours, you're a lifesaver.